# Rails web socket - authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, ember.js, authorization

I have Ember.js client and RoR server side with gem "websocket-rails".

I need to get private channel with authorization to send messages only for one user.

This is how I try:

```
class AuthorizationController < WebsocketRails::BaseController

    before_action :require_login

    def authorize_channels
        # The channel name will be passed inside the message Hash
        puts '*'*400
        ap current_user//Here I see the user

        channel = WebsocketRails[message[:channel]]
        accept_channel current_user

    end


    def require_login

        sign_in(User.find(4))

    end
end
```

My events.rb is:

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do
    namespace :websocket_rails do
        subscribe :subscribe, :to => AuthorizationController, :with_method => :authorize_channels
    end

end
```

But when I try to send message with:

```
WebsocketRails.users[4].trigger(:test_event, { message: 'This is a private message from WebSocket Rails' } )
```

I get error ``` #<NoMethodError: undefined method ``trigger' for #<WebsocketRails::UserManager::MissingConnection:0x007ff5bb50dc88>> ```

And if I try to print WebsocketRails.users I see:

```
#<WebsocketRails::UserManager:0x007ff5bb617d68 @users={}>
```

What is wrong? 
Thx a lot!

Comment: It seems no connection are extablished, how do you establish it?

Comment: I use https://github.com/fusionrsrch/ember-cli-websocket-rails gem, and that works because I see connection in debugger and can send event with public_channel https://yadi.sk/i/hhBu29LtjPhmD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u use rails-api gem, it disables a session, that was the problem.